# How to execute dynamic query in anypoint studio?

Tags: anypoint-studio

currently I am trying to create one application using Any point studio. But stuck here...

I am having two select query to fetch the data from two different tables of a single database and according to the request it will decide from which table the data will be fetched.

I'm able to create the dynamic query which will take the dynamic table name and column name. But, I wanted to take two different query. As the column name in the where clause is different for both.
please help me out...

Thanks

Comment: I am using the database connector for configuring the database .

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use MEL expressions in the database connector by choosing "Dynamic" type select query. So you only have to put the correct clause on a string variable and reference it on the connector.

Anyway, I would not try that approach. I would place a "choose" flow control and two database connectors and decide which of them use base on your condition. I would use "Parametrized" type select query, it is more secure than using "Dynamic".

Best regards,
José